# Android Client - Java Server, client doesn't connect if the order weren't done in the right way

Tags: java, android, server, client

I've got a problem with my application which is using a server - client system.
Since I am beginner and not able to get some usefull information out of the Android development manual, I have used this tutorial:
http:
//www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/ . I reformed this because I don't need to send Strings from the Server to the client. However I got the problem, that I need to keep the "connecting order". Now I would like to know, how I can write a task, which is running all the time in the background if there is no connection to the server (based in the Android application).

This is the code I tried, but it is not working:

```
public void checkConnection() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                do {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                socket = new Socket("192.168.178.52", 9090);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not connected yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error1: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } while (!socket.isConnected());
                Thread.sleep(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error2: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

if I am starting the app in the right order (1. server, 2. client), the app is working, if not, it doen't. Also I didn't get the part with the AsyncTask and the interface, which is doing what?? But thats not the topic.
Here my AsyncTask, which is reformed:

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        checkConnection();
    }

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) { // method for receiving the message
                publishProgress(message); // method calls the OnProgressUpdate
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run(); // running the whole Client
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance and please excuse my worse English.